# Purpose of Throughput Controller?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need some help to use JMeter. I want to record two different scenarios like clicking 2 different buttons. If i try to run for 2 users, one user should hit first button, another should hit another button concurrently.

I know this is the basic question. But i am new to this one. Thats why asking here. I have tried like below:

```
Thread Group
 -Throughput Controller
       --Login
       --Clicking 1st button
 -Throughput controller
       --Login
       --Clicking 2nd button
```

When i run with 2 users using CSV Data Set Config, both login takes same user.

And also i need to test for concurrency. I am not sure how to execute this one correctly. Could anyone can help me in this?

Comment: What settings did you use for the Throughput controllers?

Comment: percentage execution is 50. I want that 2 users should do 2 different actions.How to do this?

Comment: I like the [jmeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) for this one: _"This controller is badly named, as it does not control throughput."_ ... however you are trying to use it for its correct purpose

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Throughput Controller will work correct if you have more than single iteration.
   I.e. you should have N loops (using Loop Controller e.g.) with child Throughput Controller set X percents (X is integer, 0 <= X <= 100) - so than X% from N loops is integer value too.
   You may look into [this discussion](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-throughput-controller-work-td3328412.html) for better examples and explanations.
2. For your case you can try to use construction like the following:

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads = 2
Loop Count = 1
+- While Controller
   Condition = ${__javaScript("${login}"!="<EOF>",)}
   +- CSV Data Set Config
      Filename = users.csv
      Variable Names = login,pwd
      Delimiter = ,
   +- Loop Controller
      Loop Count = 10
      +- Login
      +- Throughput Controller
         Percent Execution
         Throughput = 50.0
         +- Clicking 1st button
      +- Throughput Controller
         Percent Execution
         Throughput = 50.0
         +- Clicking 2nd button
      +- Logout
```

where

 - there are 2 threads (Thread Group: Number of Threads = 2) started simultaneously each with unique credentials extracted from csv-file (While Controller + CSV Data Set Config), used for Login;

 - the whole test-flow - login > click button (either first or second) > logout - will be repeated N times using Loop Controller, which one makes Throughput Controller work.

Comment: Thanks Alies. 1. The problem is that again it takes 2 same users. I have tried as per your reply. 2. And also the Login Sampler works fine when run individually . But with concurrency it is not working. It's asking like enter your password like that in response data. But works fine individually for all users. Could you plz tell me what to do??

Comment: Hm. This example works fine for me (the only difference is that I extract urls from csv and sent requests to extracted urls instead of clicking button 1/2). Ensure that credentials are correctly extracted from csv and sent with login request - unique for each user (check requests sent as well as you can use Debug Sampler to see variables values), check jmeter.log for errors... at least. Double check field values and params in controllers/samplers.

Comment: I do not see also any need to login separately with each Throughput Controller - used construction will use unique values for the single login sampler. But this is insignificant.

Comment: Now it works:) The problem is with my CSV file. Thanks a lot Alies.

Comment: Fine. You can as well accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks.