# Jmeter:- How to achieve fluctuated TPS in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to get fluctuation in TPS using JMeter like given below

- 1  TPS to 10 TPS --  60 minutes
- 2  TPS to 4  TPS --  next 60 minutes
- 10 TPS to 15 TPS --  for next 60 Minutes
- 1  TPS to 3  TPS --  for next 60 minutes

How to achieve such various TPS with respect to time.
I am using jmeter 4.0
My Requests are like
Login Application
Create Order
Active Order
Disconnect order
Cancel Order

- Users: 300
- Ramp Up: 300 seconds
- Duration 4 Hours (14400 seconds)

Application can handle upto 45 TPS (Already Tested this)
Here we want to Check Semaphore and Server Res. memory are increasing/decreasing as per TPS increase/Decrease. (This is my target of this test)

Answer (score 1):

For Your case you can use below link to understand the tree to create and use of throughput controller-
[Purpose of Throughput Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379033/purpose-of-throughput-controller)

And I would suggest you to use multiple Once only controller and apply throughput controller with each of them and define the throughput values you want to achieve one by one, For Example

- Thread Group
- Runtime Controller (60 minutes)
- once only controller

  - HTTP Sampler
  - Throughput controller (1 TPS to 10 TPS)
- Run-time Controller (next 60 minutes)
- Once Only Controller

  - HTTP Sampler
  - Throughput Controller (2 TPS to 4 TPS)

You can see the progress in listeners( In graphical form).

Hope It works :)

Comment: Thanks for your help
I tried your concept and looks run time controller not working and request firing even the seconds expired

Comment: You have to arrange the Runtime,Once Only Controller, and wait time between each of the requests to maintain the throughput in the way you want.
I had the same kind of requirement and was able to achieve, If you can share any snapshot of how you have designed it, I'll be better able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

In your case 3 lines with Hold Load For 3600 seconds

Each line will have different Initial delay, first is 0, second is 3600 (hour) and third is 7200 (2 hours)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply...
Here I cannot use ultimate thread group because I need to Active all the users (sessions) throughout test

Comment: All the users should come once within 2-3 hours and do activities, all the user's session should active all the time which can be verified from database, same session